# I got 504-Gateway time out error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, unicorn, digital-ocean

When I open my rails app, I get a 504-Gateway timeout error.

Result of `tail /var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.169.153.194, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "162.243.204.173"
2014/01/27 12:38:05 [error] 621#0: *63 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.169.153.194, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "162.243.204.173"
2014/01/27 13:05:53 [error] 621#0: *73 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.169.153.194, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "162.243.204.173"
2014/01/27 13:16:28 [error] 621#0: *77 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.169.153.194, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "162.243.204.173"
2014/01/27 13:18:49 [error] 621#0: *80 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.169.153.194, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "162.243.204.173"
```

Then, the content of `tail /home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log`:

```
* Restarting Unicorn web server unicorn                                                                                                [ OK ] 
root@liquorexam:/home/rails# tail /home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn    /http_server.rb:303:in `join'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
E, [2014-01-27T13:16:14.982896 #20809] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid   
21135 exit 1> worker=0
I, [2014-01-27T13:16:14.983194 #20809]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2014-01-27T13:16:14.988711 #21141]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=21141
I, [2014-01-27T13:16:15.019707 #21141]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
```

Answer (score 2):

Your backend unicorn worker process is crashing, but you only including the bottom part of the stack trace.  The complete stack trace in the `unicorn.log` file will show you what in your application code is crashing.  I would guess bad middleware or a malformed response.